# BillingClient: getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 6

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I've integrated Google inApp billing in my android App. It was working fine, But now I noticed that on one device its always returning `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR` response. In Logcat it shows following error.

```
BillingClient: getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 6
```

I couldn't find any help regarding this issue, Can someone help me what could be the possible problems and solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This generally happens when you have signed out from Google account in your device. All you need to do is just sign in again, if needed do a full restart.

Comment: In my case, it was due to having three different Google accounts registered in my device, and only one of them having testing permissions. I fixed the problem by removing the other accounts from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my situation is the connection between my device and google's servers is unstable.Try to open the GooglePlay,and check if the connection is healthy.And it wroks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened when a new app I submitted was in "Draft" status, not yet approved by Google. Just wait until it's approved and payments will start to work.

An alternative would be to submit it in the internal track and add the email for you play account as a test user.